# Ansible with Github: Permission denied (Publickey)

Tags: ssh, python, git, ansible, github

I'm trying to understand the GitHub ssh configuration with Ansible (I'm working on the Ansible: Up & Running book). I'm running into two issues.

**Permission denied (publickey)** -
When I first ran the `ansible-playbook mezzanine.yml` playbook, I got a permission denied:

```
failed: [web] => {"cmd": "/usr/bin/git ls-remote '' -h refs/heads/HEAD", "failed": true, "rc": 128}
stderr: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

msg: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

Ok, fair enough, I see several people have had this problem. So I jumped to appendix A on running Git with SSH and it said to run the ssh-agent and add the id_rsa public key:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Output: `Identity Added`I ran `ssh-agent -l` to check and got the long string: `2048 e3:fb:...` But I got the same output. So I checked the Github docs on ssh key generations and troubleshooting which recommended updating the ssh config file on my host machine:

```
Host github.com
    User git
    Port 22
    Hostname github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
    TCPKeepAlive yes
    IdentitiesOnly yes
```

But this still provides the same error. So at this point, I start thinking it's my rsa file, which leads me to my second problem.

**Key Generation Issues** - I tried to generate an additional cert to use, because the Github test threw another "Permission denied (publickey)" error.

```
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.131' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I followed the Github instructions from scratch and generated a new key with a different name.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "me@example.com"
```

I didn't enter a passphrase and saved it to the .ssh folder with the name git_rsa.pub. I ran the same test and got the following:

```
$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/git_rsa.pub -T git@github.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0644 for '/Users/antonioalaniz1/.ssh/git_rsa.pub' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
bad permissions: ignore key: ~/.ssh/github_rsa.pub
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I checked on the permissions and did a `chmod 700` on the file and I still get `Permission denied (publickey)`. I even attempted to enter the key into my Github account, but first got a message that the key file needs to start with `ssh-rsa`. So I started researching and hacking. Started with just entering the long string in the file (it started with --BEGIN PRIVATE KEY--, but I omitted that part after it failed); however, Github's not accepting it, saying it's invalid.

This is my Ansible command in the YAML file:

```
- name: check out the repository on the host
  git: repo={{ repo_url }} dest={{ proj_path }} accept_hostkey=yes

  vars:
    repo_url: git@github.com:lorin/mezzanine-example.git
```

This is my ansible.cfg file with ForwardAgent configured:

```
[defaults]
hostfile = hosts
remote_user = vagrant
private_key_file = .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
host_key_checking = False

[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

The box is an Ubuntu Trusty64 using Mac OS. If anyone could clue me into the file permissions and/or Github key generation, I would appreciate it.

Comment: `$ ssh -i ~/.ssh/git_rsa.pub -T git@github.com` I don't know about your other problems, but you're using the wrong key file here. `-i` takes the name of a _private_ key file, that is, the file without the _.pub_ extension. You most likely should run `ssh -i ~/.ssh/git_rsa ...`

Comment: @Kenster Sorry for the confusion, I tried both, but they get permission denied (publickey). I'm relooking through the Github troubleshooting now and working through it again to hopefully find something.

Answer (score 2):

I had `transport = paramiko` in my `ansible.cfg` to fix a different bug but seems to be causing issues with `ForwardAgent=yes`.
Just removed the transport and it's working again.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to reorder your `~/.ssh/` dir, the `~/.ssh/config` file. `IdentifyFile` is not needed if your public keys are with the default name (`ìd_rsa.pub`, `id_ed25519.pub`, `id_dsa.pub`)
2. Check if you have an `ansible.cfg` file inside the dir where is the playbook (your *.yml file), this one will have preference over your default `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` config.
3. The permissions are for the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` private file (i have mine with `0x600`).

offtopic: "The box is an Ubuntu Trusty64 using Mac OS" ?!?!